# How to display the serial number of the table rows in descending order in php?

Tags: php, while-loop, counter

I am looking way to sort the serial number of the table in descending order. I am using a here simple while loop, with a counter variable inside it.

**Code sample:**

```
       $i= 0;
       while(condition)
       {
           $i++; 
         echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
       }
```

**Output:**

[image: Screen shot showing output of while loop]

I am not using an autoincrement column here. I just want it with a simple counter, but in descending order.

**example:**

```
#
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)? This should be a preferable solution rather than generating the numbers with PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have loop outputting the 1-10 version, you could simple change the output to show 11 minus the current count...

```
echo "<td>".(11-$i)."</td>";
```

Or to change the whole code, you could start at 11 and decrement the counter each time and output it that way

```
$i= 11;
while($i>0)
{
    $i--;
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
}
```

Comment: thank you for its works! I got an idea from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

count first and after do a loop in reverse order

```
   $i= 0;
   while(condition)
   {
       $i++; 

   }
   for ( cnt= $i, $i>= 0, $i--){
         echo "<td>".$cnt."</td>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching from MYSQL Database and you're using PDO to connect to Database

```
//COUNT THE TOTAL NUMBER OF ROWS RETURNED
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_tnxs ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $con->query($sql);
$stmt_num_rows = $stmt->fetch();
$tot_rows = array_shift($stmt_num_rows);
$sn = $tot_rows

while(){
 $sn--;
 echo '<td>' . $sn . '</td>';
}
```

So whatever the total number of rows you have - fetching from the database it'll countdown to '0'using the while loop.
I have been looking for this for long but later figured it out myself so I decided to drop it here for anyone it might be helpful to...